# Why do my questions on the etymology of idioms get closed, yet this one was accepted?: What is the origin of "out of sight" or "outa sight" i?

Tags: discussion, etymology

Every question I have asked about the etymology of an idiom gets pulled.  Yet I found this one that stayed up. It's espcially irritating because sometimes before my question gets closed, I have recieved useful respsonses.  I don't post a question unless I have researched all the etymology I can find online.

Comment: Total guess, but probably because they violate site policies. It's also quite common for people to claim they have researched etymology but not document their research in the question - the requirement is not just to do the research but to describe in the question what research you have done. And (not criticising "out of sight" specifically) some questions which remain up are bad questions, especially if they're older from when the rules were different. But you seem to think we're psychic, which makes me suspect you thought we were able to read your mind and tell if you did research.

Comment: I understand the concern for random questions, but I'm a published historian, and when I have an etymological question, StackExchange is the only place to go for expert opinions. I participate in several historical listservs and I have no problem with unserious questions--I just scroll past them. In the past, I have gotten a standard reason for closing the question about "a reasonable assumption of systematicity, by situating themselves within a historical context of language..."  I don't see any of that "systematicity" or "context" in the "out of sight" question.

Comment: Heartspring said, "You should link the questions and ask this on [Meta]."  How do I do that?

Comment: Do you in fact post your research? 'Collins Dictionary, AHD, M-W and the Online Etymological Dictionary do not help' (if true) is valid. // I've checked and can only find one (other)  question that you've posted. It contains references and has been answered and upvoted. If you've deleted closed questions, 'Why have my questions on ... been closed?' is hardly a fair question to put before the community.

Comment: Well, since the questions have been deleted they can't be linked easily- you can, however, paste their content into blockquotes. As for meta-migration, we've already moved it here.

Comment: What is "this one which stayed up"? Please [edit] to include links. As for being a published author, congratulations! But the community didn't know that, and even that accolade doesn't mean that you have actually done any research. At least say where you looked. As it stands, the question here is so vague that I'm not sure it can be answered: please do make it more specific.

Answer (score 5):

No question of yours asked on our main site has been “pulled” — whatever you meant by that. Certainly not even one has yet been deleted.  You have to date asked exactly three questions on English Language and Usage, which I list here prefixed by the precise timestamp at which you posted them and ordered oldest to youngest:

1. `2023-04-25 13:55:57Z` [What is the etymology of the expression "spit bath"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/606591)
2. `2023-10-12 14:48:20Z` [Why do my questions on the etymology of idioms get closed, yet this one was accepted?: What is the origin of "out of sight" or "outa sight" i?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613560)
3. `2023-10-12 16:14:22Z` [What is the recent etymology of the American expression "mosey''?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613561)

Your second question was correctly migrated here to our meta site where it should have been posted, and migration automatically locks the original on the site of origin; it will eventually be deleted by routine system clean-up services in the fullness of time.

The other two questions you have asked are both still available for interactions.

Although some members of our site may quibble a bit with the notion that an idiomatic expression comprising multiple words can have an “etymology” rather than an origin or history, that really doesn’t influence whether someone deleted your questions from the site. No one has done that.

Comment: The closed question was asked on [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/47675/22150).